# how to convert date coming from api endpoint from unix to localtime

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm getting my date response and storedin local variable **responsedata** and mapped from **customdata** I want to cover that date coming from **i.logs[0].datetime** to local time string! just stored all data in **apidata** state so I can forward them as props. the main question in **datetime** here im getting a date in unix formate but i want to conver it into local time!!

````
  useEffect(() => {
    const postdata = {
      api_key: apiKey,
      format: "json",
      logs: 1,
      custom_uptime_ranges: "1658892600_1658979000-1658946600_1659033000",
    };
    const url = "https://api.uptimerobot.com/v2/getMonitors";
    const getData = async () => {
      await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      }).then(async (response) => {
        const responseData = await response.json();
        const customData = responseData.monitors.map((i) => ({
          title: i.friendly_name,
          uptime: i.custom_uptime_ranges,
          date: i.logs[0].datetime,
        }));
        console.log(responseData);

        setApiData(customData);
        console.log(apidata);
      });
    };
    getData();
  }, [apidata]);```
````

Comment: I think that it's what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: toLocalDateString will do the thing but I stored it in a local variable and mapped from it so I just basically don't know how to access that **date** from outside!!

Comment: @Yumie Hii, const localDate = new Date(props.date * 1000).toLocaleDateString(); i passed that date to another component and convert there thanks